# Half of threads randomly not completing and vanishing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5, python-3.8

So I currently have a PYQT application utilizing a combination of pythons built-in threading, and QT Qthread/worker system to allow for asynchronous activities

The code for generating the threads/workers is process_batch which is contained in a class called Scraper, which is a QObject

```
def process_batch(self, batch):
    for worker in batch:
        self.host.threads.append(QThread())
        th = self.host.threads[len(self.host.threads)-1]
        worker.moveToThread(th)
        th.started.connect(worker.process)
        qApp.aboutToQuit.connect(th.quit)
        worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
        th.finished.connect(th.deleteLater)
    for thread in self.host.threads:
        thread.start()
        self.activeThreads += 1
```

the the self.host.threads is a list variable helf by the ScraperHost object, the batch variable is a standard python list with 50 of the following class:

```
class ScraperWorker(QObject):
    complete = pyqtSignal(str)
    start = pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, url, task, _id):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.task = task
        self.id = _id
        self.start.connect(self.process)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

    @pyqtSlot()
    def process(self):
        time.sleep(float(random.random() * random.randint(1,3)))      
        #self.complete.emit(str(self.id))
        self.finished.emit()
```

The time.sleep was added to see if spacing out the thread's completions randomly would fix the issue, it did not

Originally I was running into an issue of the threads getting deleted before finishing when the process_batch function completed, so I implemented the self.host.threads to keep them from getting garbage collected.

threads are contained below in :

```
class ScraperHost(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, urls, task):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.scraper = Scraper(urls, task, self)
        self.threads = []

    def run(self):
        self.scraper.run()
```

The scraper host is created in my MainWindow by:

```
def selectFileList(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select List","", "Excel File (*.xls *.xlsx)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            ...
            ...
            self.ScraperHost = ScraperHost(0, urls, "index")
            self.ScraperHost.run()
```

As it is currently I am able to run the function/program with zero errors, but it only completes exactly half of the threads prior to finishing. It gives me no errors, messages, or any indication as to why they aren't finishing. If I increase the batch size to 100, it finishes 50. If I run it in debug mode in VS Code, i can see that all 50 threads are created correctly, and are all in the host. threads variable. If ** I step through the thread's creation 1 by 1 in debug mode they will all finish correctly**, but if I just run the program normally only exactly half will finish. The 25 threads that finish are different every time due to the random time they wait. The `self.finished.emit()` of the worker just prints the thread's ID, which is how I am seeing how many finish

EDIT: Reproducable Sample: Side Note: Gets through more, sometimes all, but with no consistency, of the threads when ran from idle as opposed to VS Code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


import threading
import time
import random

scraperhost = None

class ScraperHost(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, urls, task):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.scraper = Scraper(urls, task, self)
        self.threads = []

    def run(self):
        self.scraper.run()

class Scraper(QObject):
    output = pyqtSignal(str)
    complete = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, urls, task, host):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.urls = urls
        self.batches = []
        self.activeThreads = 0
        self.task = task
        self.host = host

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        batch_size = 50 
        batch_count = 1
        for batch in range(0, batch_count):
            self.batches.append([])
            for i in range (0, batch_size):
                try:
                    c_url = "www.website.com"
                    worker = ScraperWorker(c_url, self.task, i)
                    worker.complete.connect(self.worker_finished)
                    self.batches[batch].append(worker)
                except IndexError:
                    break
        if len(self.batches) == 0:
            return
        self.process_batch(self.batches.pop())

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def worker_finished(self, ss):
        self.activeThreads -= 1  
        print(self.activeThreads)



    def process_batch(self, batch):
        for worker in batch:
            self.host.threads.append(QThread())
            th = self.host.threads[len(self.host.threads)-1]
            worker.moveToThread(th)
            th.started.connect(worker.process)
            qApp.aboutToQuit.connect(th.quit)
            worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
            th.finished.connect(th.deleteLater)
        for thread in self.host.threads:
            thread.start()
            self.activeThreads += 1


class ScraperWorker(QObject):
    complete = pyqtSignal(str)
    start = pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, url, task, _id):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.url = url
        self.task = task
        self.id = _id
        self.start.connect(self.process)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url

    @pyqtSlot()
    def process(self):
        time.sleep(float(random.random() * random.randint(1,3)))      
        self.complete.emit(str(self.id))
        self.finished.emit()









def main():

    app = QApplication([])
    ex = QWidget()
    ex.show()
    global scraperhost
    scraperhost = ScraperHost(0, [], "index")
    scraperhost.start()
    app.exec_()
    return

main()
```

Comment: change `self.ScraperHost.run()` to `self.ScraperHost.start()`

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc i added a sample, and changing it from run to start didn't affect anything, running it in idle provides better results than VS code, but the amount of threads that complete varies greatly now, sometimes completing all of them, sometimes not